# Simple database driven website in a corporate environment?

Tags: html, web-applications, web

Despite having a degree in electrical engineering, my manager tasked me with creating a website that allows day shift engineers to pass information to the night shift engineers and vice versa.

The user site is just going to have some forms for people to leave feedback, outstanding issues etc.It should also have an archive that allows you to see what was passed down on prior days.

I need to be able to develop it on my computer and then pass it to the administrators to host.

I feel confident I can work out the actual coding, but the options on software/languages to accomplish this are a bit overwhelming.

Any ideas for the best approach?

Comment: You can keep it simple with PHP, MySQL, HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an issue tracker? Look at existing solutions, e.g. Mantis.

Comment: Should I setup a virtual server on my work computer and run PHP and MySQL from that? Also the Mantis software looks good, but I already made a sharepoint page with similar functionality that we use.